# One child of the node returns Null

Tags: android, firebase

I am try to get the value from the Firebase database.I get all the values except one. And this is happening here only. I have accessed the same value earlier and it was working fine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylAgL.png) This is my database.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O6jj.png) This is my Code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyfl8.png) This is my class [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l28FY.png)
Please let me know what i am doing wrong.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up `userNumber` and `usernumber` in your code. Try to use just one of them and see if the problem persists

Comment: not working. I have used the same method to get same value and it wrking fine. but here it is giving the value null although dataSnapshot has the value